# CORS on well-known endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to configure a javascript client to use oauth code flow for accessing an API behind WSO2 API Manager. The library I'm using requires that I provide the well-known endpoint so it automatically fetches everything needed. The problem is I'm getting a CORS error while getting https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration.

I have allow all origins both on [cors] and [apim.cors] sections of deployment.toml.

As far as I know, this should work. Since, Identity server 5.11.0 deployment.toml or APIS are preferred over the cors filter on web-inf.xml. Am I missing something?

PS: I'm using version 4.0.0 of the api manager.

Comment: You need to use the cors filter in Tomcat

Comment: @Pubci yes, i know that. But here I'm asking why it doesn't work with the [cors] configuration which i think it should.